# Can't view orders in admin if quote or product is deleted

Tags: magento2, admin

When trying to open some orders from the order grid in the admin panel, the resulting page is mostly blank. I don't see any customer details, order line items, totals, etc.  When looking at the `system.log` I see errors like this for different orders

```
[2017-06-05 23:05:25] main.CRITICAL: No such entity with cartId = 67 [] []
[2017-06-05 23:06:34] main.CRITICAL: Requested product doesn't exist [] []
```

That seems to suggest that if either the quote for the order, or the product ordered, was deleted, it can't be shown in the admin.

I checked the MySQL database and it seems to support this theory.  If the `sales_order.quote_id` doesn't exist, or the `sales_order.quote_id` -> `quote_item.sku` doesn't exist you can't view the order.

Is this is bug?  Isn't deleting quotes and products a normal operation?